# Google analytics API using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am a beginner to javascript.I am using google embed api and need data to be fetched from a particular view in a particular account. I checked with google's documentation, they have a view selector but I want to access just one view.

Also there is no mention to the reportType in any of the documentation, what is it used for?

```
    var timeline = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
    reportType: 'ga', //Kindly explain this
    query: {
      'dimensions': 'ga:date',   //what if i want to access a more specific view (i have the view id)**
      'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
      'start-date': '30daysAgo',
      'end-date': 'yesterday',
    },
    chart: {
      type: 'LINE',
      container: 'timeline'
    }
});
```

Please help me directly access a dimension under a particular account and view using the id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it's good advice to check the Core Reporting API - it uses many of the same parameters.

"ga" is the only parameter that seems to be accepted by the GA API, see [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/metadata/v3/reference/metadata/columns/list).

If you want to only show a specific View, you need the Profile ID. You then include it via the "ids" parameter:

```
var timeline = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
reportType: 'ga', //Kindly explain this
query: {
'ids': 'ga:' + profileId,
  'dimensions': 'ga:date',
  'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
  'start-date': '30daysAgo',
  'end-date': 'yesterday',
},
chart: {
  type: 'LINE',
  container: 'timeline'
}
});
```

Comment: Hey @oliver13 it worked.. Also if I want to combine a few queries and fetch the data in JSON format, is that possible?  Because google charts is a bit confining and my dashboard needs a live feed. If i separately query the data the access limits will be exceeded.

Comment: What do you mean with a live feed? I'm not aware that bundling queries is possible.

Comment: I am trying to create a real time dashboard. ohkay, thanks for the help :)